# Show additional information under selected row in table/grid

Tags: view, sapui5

I have a list of invoices , which looks like this:

[image: Invoice list]

What I want to achieve is to show some details below selected row.
For exemple user clicked on invoice No 12345567724 (1st on list)

[image: Expaneded invoicelist]

Is there any component that allows to show those details?

Comment: This [list with expandable panels](https://github.com/ScottStefanich/UI5/tree/master/ListPanelFilter) might be of some inspiration

Comment: I thought about it but it doesn't fit for me, I need a table layout with columns header so i  can use them to sort data.

Comment: you can use common.TreeTable but I cannot recommend it, binding is very heavy, it is not very developper friendly (even with sorting and filtering). I would recommend a nice Popup or even a Navigation to a detail-page.

Comment: agreed - detail pages is how i made it for now. But i wanted to do it way which i've described. I think it would just look better.